# Problem with blog posts in integrating wordpress with existing site.

Tags: php, wordpress, post, blogs

I am trying to integrate wordpress in my existing site, so I put the wordpress files in Localhost/site/blog directory because i dont want to clatter up my root directoy, with all the includes/stylesheet/images folder.

And I also want the blog to mimic the design of my site. That's why I just created blog.php and put it in the root directory and just put this on top of my blog.php so that wordpress will work with blog.php. Even if its not inside the wordpress directory.

```
<?php 
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('./blog/wp-blog-header.php'); 
?>
```

I then put the loop in the inside the body tag, and everything seems fine and dandy. The blog posts show up. They align perfectly.

```
<!-- Start the Loop. -->        
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

 <?php if ( in_category('3') ) { ?>
           <div class="post-cat-three">
 <?php } else { ?>
           <div class="blogpostcontainer">
                <div class="blogpost">
                     <div><img src="images/blogpost_picture.jpg" width="125" height="125" alt="blogpost" /></div>
                        <div class="info">
 <?php } ?>
 <!-- Display the Title as a link to the Post's permalink. -->
 <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

   <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
 <p><span class="date"><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></span></p>
                        </div><!--END OF info div-->
                  </div><!--END OF blogpost div-->
              </div><!--END OF blogpostcontainer div-->
 <?php endwhile; else: ?>
```

NOW THE PROBLEM!!
Well, the problem is, whenever I try to click on the permalinks of the post(to view the whole post), I just get this jumbled up mess: Everything there does not have any CSS or whatsoever.

I just want to know, how can I get the posts from looking good, I know I have to create single.php or page.php?(or do I?), but I dont know where to put it. Is it inside the wp dir, or in my root?
If you have anymore questions or the question is vague. Please let me know. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`single.php` (for post) / `page.php` (for generic page) should be in your `/wp-content/themes/<active theme>/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable is that singe.php and page.php already exist.

You should change URL in the settings to localhost/site/blog

More information you can find here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory